# How to Write this question in ordinary number?

Tags: arithmetic

[image]

I'm doing a Mock Exam and I'm not sure how to do this question. I know how to multiply however I'm not sure how to do $10$ and then the $-3$ inverse. I think it is cubed ($-1000$) however I'm not sure if it is right. This is a non-calculator paper by the way. Thank you.

Comment: Use $x^{-n}=1/x^n$

Answer (score 2):

For integers $k\neq 0$

$$a\times b^{-k} = \dfrac a{b^k}$$

So, in your case,

$$4.5 \times 10^{-3} = \frac {4.5}{10^3} = \frac {4.5}{1000} = 0.0045$$

Comment: why would you devide $4$ by $1000$. I understand what you are writing however I'm not sure why you devide.

Comment: Because the multiplicative inverse of $10^{-3}=\dfrac 1{10^3}$ is $10^3$. So multiplying by $10^{-3}$ is equivalent to dividing by $10^3$.

Comment: No, $10^{-3}$ $\textbf{is}$ $\frac{1}{10^3}$; its multiplicative inverse is $10^3$.

Comment: Is the answer $0.0045$?

Comment: Yes, the answer is 0.0045. amWhy seems to have misread your question.

Comment: @Eric and Honky: yes, You're both correct. Indeed, I misread the question and was working with $4 \times ...$ instead of $4.5\times ...$ Sorry for any inadvertent confusion. Now edited and updated.